# Angular - navigating to a url after logging in

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

For example I have a url and I input it on the browser `https://developer.anduks.myproperties/#/myproperties/3664-S`

If I’m not logged in, it should take me to the login page which is currently working on my end. But, after I login, it doesn’t take me to the link I inputed on the browser like the sample link

When I input the url in the browser and I am not logged in then redirect to login page . If I input the url on the browser and hit enter and then I logged in my account it should redirect to that url input.

Anyone has an idea how to implement the problem above? Thanks.

#auth.guard.ts code

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  userProfile: any;
 
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private route: Router,) {}

  public async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    const allowedUserRoles = this.getRoutePermissions(route);
    return await this.checkPermission(allowedUserRoles);
  }

  private getRoutePermissions(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Roles[] {
    if (route.data && route.data.userRoles) {
      return route.data.userRoles as Roles[];
    }
    return null;
  }

  private checkPermission(allowedUserRoles: Roles[]): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.authService.getSession().then((session: boolean) => {
      if (session) {
        if (!allowedUserRoles) {
          return true;   // if no user roles has been set, all user are allowed to access the route
        } else {
          let userRoles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userRoles"));
          if (this.authService.areUserRolesAllowed(userRoles, allowedUserRoles)) {
            return true;
          } else {
            this.route.navigateByUrl('/transactions');
            return false;
          }
        }
      } else { return false; }
    });
  }
}
```

#app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'properties',
        loadChildren: () => import('./features/property/property.module').then(m => m.PropertyModule),
        data: {
          userRoles: [Roles.ADMIN, Roles.TRANSACTION_SUPER_USER, Roles.TRANSACTION_MANAGER]
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'settings',
        loadChildren: () => import('./features/settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule),
        data: {
          title: 'Settings',
          userRoles: [Roles.ADMIN, Roles.TRANSACTION_SUPER_USER, Roles.TRANSACTION_MANAGER]
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'transactions',
        loadChildren: () => import('./features/transactions/transactions.module').then(m => m.TransactionsModule),
        data: {
          title: 'Transactions',
          userRoles: [Roles.BROKER, Roles.ADMIN, Roles.TRANSACTION_SUPER_USER, Roles.TRANSACTION_MANAGER]
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path:'**',
    redirectTo: ''    
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true,
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create service `BeforeAuthRedirectionService`. It would have private property `url` and getter/setter. when you are returning false in canActivate guard ( when user is not logged in )  before user gets redirected to login page you have to save current url and set it in your service. after login happens you can acess that url again and redirect to that page.

Comment: How to get the url input which is for example https://developer.anduks.myproperties/#/myproperties/3664-S  ? when I input the url it directly redirects to the login page , how would I get the first url input ?

Comment: it gets redirected to login page after your guards checks whether user is authenticated or not. you can  get that url in canActivate method.  canActivate method takes second optional parameter `state:RouterStateSnapshot` and you can use state.url to access that url